# Seven Segment Decoder

Tags: hex, decimal, verilog, decoder, seven-segment-display

So I'm trying to design Seven Segment Decoder. When Button is pressed at 110, then the LED Display should display 1 digit hex number: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F. But, when Button is pressed at 101, then the LED Display should display 1 digit decimal number: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

This is my Warnings:

```
Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <out<4>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <out<5>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <out<3>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <out<2>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <out<1>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <out<0>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <out<6>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
Xst:2169 - HDL ADVISOR - Some clock signals were not automatically buffered by XST with BUFG/BUFR resources. Please use the buffer_type constraint in order to insert these buffers to the clock signals to help prevent skew problems.
```

This is my code using Xilinx design tools:

```
module hex_sch(out, in, button);
output reg [6:0] out;
input [3:0] in;
input [2:0] button;
// Low active signal should activate the LEDs
    always @(button or in) 
    begin
        if (button == 3'b110) begin
            case (in)
            //Output format gfedcba
            4'h0: out <= 7'b1000000;
            4'h1: out <= 7'b1111001;
            4'h2: out <= 7'b0100100;
            4'h3: out <= 7'b0110000;
            4'h4: out <= 7'b0011001;
            4'h5: out <= 7'b0010010;
            4'h6: out <= 7'b0000010;
            4'h7: out <= 7'b1111000;
            4'h8: out <= 7'b0000000;
            4'h9: out <= 7'b0011000;
            4'hA: out <= 7'b0001000;
            4'hB: out <= 7'b0000011;
            4'hC: out <= 7'b1000110;
            4'hD: out <= 7'b0100001;
            4'hE: out <= 7'b0000110;
            4'hF: out <= 7'b0001110;
            default: out <= 7'bx;
            endcase
            end
        else if (button == 3'b101) begin
            case (in)
            //Output format abcdefg
            4'd0: out <= 7'b1000000;
            4'd1: out <= 7'b1111001;
            4'd2: out <= 7'b0100100;
            4'd3: out <= 7'b0110000;
            4'd4: out <= 7'b0011001;
            4'd5: out <= 7'b0010010;
            4'd6: out <= 7'b0000010;
            4'd7: out <= 7'b1111000;
            4'd8: out <= 7'b0000000;
            4'd9: out <= 7'b0011000;
            default out <= 7'bx;
            endcase
            end
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: It really depends what you want on how to properly fix this. What should happen if button is set to 3'b000? Your current design is inferring latches (which might be want you want?) because the logic given if not combinational (ie, case of button is 3'b000, what should out be?). Ideally, you should be more explicit with how you set up your code if you do indeed want latches (ie, have out hold its value if button become 3'b000 for example). Otherise, you need to specific that case and get rid of your non-blocking assignment.... All depends on what you want to happen for other button values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove those warnings you must set a value for `out` in every possible `in` and `button`.
otherwise you will get a latch.

In your code you do not cover all posibilities for `button` input - you only cover 110 and 101.

An easy way to cover all posibilities in your code may be:

> ... // your module definition as is
>
> // Low active signal should activate the LEDs
>
> ```
> always @(button or in) 
> begin
>     if (button == 3'b110) begin
>         case (in)
>         //Output format gfedcba
> ```
>
> ... // your case statement as is
>
> ```
>         endcase
>     end
>     else if (button == 3'b101) begin
>         case (in)
> ```
>
> ... // your case statement as is
>
> ```
>         endcase
>     end
>     else begin
>         out <= 7'b1;
>     end
> end endmodule
> ```

This way, when button is different then 110 or 101, it will show blank.

Comment: If you are making it combinational (which you are), you should really use blocking assignments (=), not non-blocking (<=)

Comment: I agree with Unn.
It is a better practice.